# How can i make small square boxes inside panel in css

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

My Project is using `zurb foundations` but i don't know much about it.

I need to design the layout like this . This is rough drawing

The Header needs to be in center and the text inside small boxes also should be in center.

This is what i have tried

http://jsfiddle.net/utnobcL1/

The box should be around `300 width , 400height`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/utnobcL1/2/

here's a quick model for you.

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.box {
    width:100px;
    margin:auto;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.header {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:grey;
}
```

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/utnobcL1/4/

Comment: how can i makr big number 786 in the center of small box  both vertically and horizontally

Comment: Thanks , thats is what i want